# Reduce does not solve a system of equations

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to solve a system of 7 equations and 7 unknowns given a set of assuptions. I am only interested in obtaining V3 as a function of the exogenous parameters.

I am using the following code:

```
Reduce[V3 == (-12 s + 4 d V1 - 3 d l V1 + 4 d V2 - 3 d l V2 + 
    3 d l V4 + 2 d l V5 + 2 d l V6 + 2 d l V7 + 12 w1 + 12 w4)/(
   12 - 4 d + 3 d l) && 
  V2 == (-12 s + 4 d V1 - 3 d l V1 + 4 d V3 - 3 d l V3 + 3 d l V4 + 
    2 d l V5 + 2 d l V6 + 2 d l V7 + 12 w1 + 12 w3)/(
   12 - 4 d + 3 d l) && 
  V1 == (-12 s + 4 d V2 - 3 d l V2 + 4 d V3 - 3 d l V3 + 3 d l V4 + 
    2 d l V5 + 2 d l V6 + 2 d l V7 + 12 w1 + 12 w2)/(
   12 - 4 d + 3 d l) && 
  V4 == (12 s + d l V1 + d l V2 + d l V3 + 2 d l V5 + 2 d l V6 + 
    2 d l V7)/(3 (4 - 4 d + 3 d l)) && 
  V5 == (-12 b + d l V1 + d l V2 + d l V3 + 3 d l V4 + 4 d V6 - 
    2 d l V6 + 4 d V7 - 2 d l V7 + 12 w2)/(2 (6 - 2 d + d l)) && 
  V6 == (-12 b + d l V1 + d l V2 + d l V3 + 3 d l V4 + 4 d V5 - 
    2 d l V5 + 4 d V7 - 2 d l V7 + 12 w3)/(2 (6 - 2 d + d l)) && 
  V7 == (-12 b + d l V1 + d l V2 + d l V3 + 3 d l V4 + 4 d V5 - 
    2 d l V5 + 4 d V6 - 2 d l V6 + 12 w4)/(2 (6 - 2 d + d l)) && 
  w1 > s > w2 > w3 > w4 > b > 0 && w1 + w2 + w3 + w4 == 4 s && 
  0 < d < 1 && 0 < l < 1, {V3, V2, V1, V4, V5, V6, V7, s}]
```

I solved similar systems using this method and I also tried to use Solve instead of Reduce without success. However, Mathematica does not return me anything in this case.

Does anyone know a different way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This works in 12.1.1 and gives a partially reduced expression. Fortunately V3 is completely reduced: `V3 == (6 b d l - 9 w1 + 9 d w1 - 3 d l w1 + 3 w2 - 7 d w2 + 4 d^2 w2 + d l w2 - 4 d^2 l w2 + 3 w3 - 7 d w3 + 4 d^2 w3 + d l w3 - 4 d^2 l w3 - 9 w4 + 17 d w4 - 8 d^2 w4 - 11 d l w4 +  8 d^2 l w4)/(-12 + 24 d - 12 d^2 - 12 d l + 12 d^2 l)`

Comment: Use `Solve[eqs, {V3, V2, V1, V4, V5, V6, V7, s}] // Simplify`, where `eqs` is the set of all eight equations in the question, but none of the inequalities to obtain solutins for all  eight variables.  The only constraints on the solution are that neither `(-1 + d)` nor `(1 + d (-1 + l))` vanish.

Comment: I have the version 12.1.1 and it is not working to me @flinty Did you just copied and paste my code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeah I did. It executes in about three to four seconds. The results look very similar to the input but look closer and you'll see it has got rid of all the Vi in V3, and I copied that into my comment above. I am on 12.1.1 for Windows 10 by the way.

Comment: Thanks @flinty, it worked perfectly now!